# how to make YOLOv7 use only part of the GPU?

Tags: python, computer-vision, gpu, object-detection, yolo

I am trying to train the YOLOv7 network, but I should limit the GPU usage to 8Gb.
What I understood doing experiments also on Google Colab is that before starting the training, the network tries to occupy most of the available memory regardless of how much it is or how much it is needed for training. In fact, on Google Colab it requires 11 GB out of 14 to start the training, while on my GPU it requires 45 out of 50, although then the actual training phase requires only 6GB.

I tried to minimize the parameters (batch size, workers) but nothing changes as, as mentioned, the problem is the pre-training allocation which is fixed.

I tried using the function of pytorch
`torch.cuda.set_per_process_memory_fraction(0.16, CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES)`

but this function does not cause the network to use only 8GB but causes, if exceeded 8GB, an error.

on YOLOX there is the "-o" parameter which, if omitted, avoids the allocation of pre-training memory and therefore uses only the memory it needs during training but I have not found the equivalent of this parameter on YOLOv7.

Is it possible to make YOLOv7 see only 8GB available and therefore allocate a smaller amount of GB?
Or is it possible that pre-training allocation is avoided like in YOLOX?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example